# Linked List issue when inserting a new item in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the next implementation of Linked List:

```js
class Node {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class LinkedLIst {
  constructor() {
    this.head = {};
  }

  add(head) {    
    if(!this.head.next) {
      this.head = new Node(head);
    }

    this.head.next = new Node(head);
  }
}


const list = new LinkedLIst();
list.add(1)
list.add(2)
list.add(3)


console.log(list)
```

I don't understand, why `2` is not added within the list? And how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a linked list, I am assuming you want to insert at the end. To do that, you can create a `tail` property.

Then, in you `add` method, you can check if no elements exist, then set the `head` and `tail` to the new node. If there is at least 1 element, you can set the `tail`'s next to the new node and finally, make the `tail` point to the new node.

```js
class Node {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class LinkedLIst {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
  }

  add(value) {    
    const newNode = new Node(value)
    if (this.head === null) {
      this.head = this.tail = newNode
    } else {
      this.tail.next = newNode
      this.tail = newNode;
    }
  }
}


const list = new LinkedLIst();
list.add(1)
list.add(2)
list.add(3)


console.log(list)
```

Comment: could you please explain his statement ` this.tail.next = newNode
      this.tail = newNode;`?

Comment: Basically, your previous `tail` is going to be the second last element after you insert a new element. So, you are connecting the `tail`'s next to the `newNode`. Once done, you want to update the `tail` again to point to the last node which is going to be the `newNode`

Comment: what is the purpose of `tail`?

Comment: As the name suggests, `head` tracks the first node of the linked list, and `tail` tracks the last node of the linked list.

Comment: could you explain please why my example does not work?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use tail just iterate until the end of the linklist

```js
class Node {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class LinkedLIst {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
  }

  add(head) {    
    
    if(!this.head) {
      this.head = new Node(head);
    }else{
      let ptr = this.head;    
      while(ptr.next!==null){
        ptr = ptr.next;
      }
      ptr.next=new Node(head);
    }
    
    
  }
}


const list = new LinkedLIst();
list.add(1)
list.add(2)
list.add(3)


console.log(list)
```

Comment: why do i need `ptr ` variable, why i can not use `this.head` instead?

Comment: You need to because you alway want to add the latest node to the end of the list